# where is D6's statistics_counter in D7?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I want show the number of  views count in node.tpl.php with Drupal 7, but I cant find  the Drupal 7 Equivalent of statistics_counter.

where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **Statistics** module shows you how often a given page is viewed, who
>   viewed it, the previous page the user visited (referrer URL), and when
>   it was viewed.
>
> In Drupal 7 configure statistics via **configuration > statistics**.
>
> To enable collection of statistics, the ***Enable access log*** checkbox on
>   the Statistics settings page must be checked.
>
> Enable ***Count content views*** to turn on and off the node-counting
>   functionality. If turned on, an extra database
>   query is added for each node displayed, which increments a counter.

Make sure you set permissions for the module at admin/user/permissions and configure it.

Based on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) and http://groups.drupal.org/node/147619

Comment: You need the `view post access counter` permission to see the statistics_counter pseudo-link.